# Css on Internet Explorer and media queries

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I have this css code that it works fine with this on IE:

```
/*IE */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

.shape{
    margin-top: -50px!important;
}

} 
/*End of IE */
```

But when I try to add the code to smaller devices with media query like this:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 992px){
   /*IE */
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

    .shape{
        margin-top: -70px!important;
    }

    } 
    /*End of IE */
}
```

This does not work..
Can someone please tell me how is it possible to work the internet explorer css on media queries also..?

Comment: Well combine the two into one …?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you have nested media queries - this is not doable. Instead combine them together:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 992px)
and (-ms-high-contrast: none)
and (-ms-high-contrast: active)
{
    .shape{margin-top: -70px!important;}
} 
/*End of IE */
```